# Issue connecting to database using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to connect to a postgres database using JDBC in eclipse. However, when running my code I get the error    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

I went to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/ to download the required JAR and sources and have tried many different versions. I don't understand the error considering I have the required JAR in my build path and the JAR contains source code.

Attached is a screenshot of my code on Eclipse. [image: Eclipse Java Code]

Comment: It seems the driver in the classpath... but somehow is not. How are you running the app?

Comment: @TheImpaler on the console.

Comment: Post text rather than images.

Comment: By the way… `Class.forName` has not been needed for *many* years. Modern Java automatically loads your JDBC driver via the [Java SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to create a file in my project and store the JAR there. Then I added the JAR to my build path. Originally, I was storing the JAR in an external location and choosing to build the path with an "External JAR"

Comment: You will find development simpler if you let Maven or Gradle drive your project, download your dependencies (needed libraries), and compile/build your app. There is a bit of a learning curve, but well worth it. You'll find many articles and tutorials, as Maven & Gradle are both very popular and commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JavaDatabaseConnection {
    public static Connection connection;

    public Connection open() {
    
        try {
            connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_NAME", "DB_USER_NAME","DB_PASSWORD");
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't Connect to database : "+ e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void close() {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

now you can connect with your DB. In my dao file i call like this

```
private static final String QUERY_INSERT_FOOD_MENU = "insert into " + DATABASE_SCHEMA + "." + TABLE_FOOD_MENU +
            "( " + COLUMN_MENU_NAME + ", " + COLUMN_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME + ", " + COLUMN_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME + " ) values(?, ?, ?);";

private JavaDatabaseConnection connection = new JavaDatabaseConnection();
public Connection jdbcConnection() {
            return connection.open();
        }
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(QUERY_INSERT_FOOD_MENU);
        
        

try (PreparedStatement insertIntoFoodMenu = jdbcConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_INSERT_FOOD_MENU);
                    Statement statement = jdbcConnection().createStatement()){
    //.....
    }catch{
    //...
    }
```

I think it helps you, Thank you.